# NiceLabel VBScript - Adding Variables

Tags: vbscript

x and y are always numeric.

x, y, and Quantity are always "1" by default if the user does not change values.
I've set y = 4.

When running the code below, I receive error:
Variable "Quantity" has format Numeric. Value "4+1-1" is invalid for this format"

```
Dim x, y, z, result
x = EndingLabel.Value
y = BarcodedNumber.Value
z = x & "+" & 1 & "-" & y
result = z
If (z > y) Then
Quantity.Value = result
Else
End If
```

I'm not certain if the problem is my code or the program I'm writing it in, but it doesn't appear to be calculating the actual equation "4+1-1".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "4+1-1" isn't an equation as there is no equal signs in the expression.

Comment: Thanks!  Wish I'd have asked an hour ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that "4+1-1" isn't being seen as a string which it is. I'd suggest putting an ["Eval"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094(v=vs.84).aspx) around it so that it is taken in that form. Change the assignment of `z` to this:

```
z = eval(x & "+" & 1 & "-" & y)
```

If you want another way to consider this. Think of a `2` that in code could be the digit 2, an ASCII character of the digit 2 or something else and thus interpretation is a key point here.